# Unreadable characters from Python to csv file

Tags: python, csv, twitter, character-encoding, ubuntu-18.04

I'm a linguistics student and I'm downloading tweets in Italian for my thesis, I've been reading previous answers to similar problems but none of them worked for me: after downloading them, if I read them in PyCharm terminal my tweets are perfectly readable, but when I open the csv file, doesn't matter the program, LibreOffice (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04), Excel 2010, Txt, characters like "é è à" and so on are visualized as a unicode string.
I tried every tutorial here and elsewhere, but I'm not having success, any idea of what could I do? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options you can try.

1. **Use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)** (free trial): Open your CSV file, then `Save with encoding...` and choose "UTF-8"
2. **Import (rather than open) with Excel**: Open blank sheet. Then `Import`, choose `CSV File`. In the following Assistant choose "UTF-8" as Source.

[image]